# (iOS) How can I speed up the reaction time of "didReceiveLocalNotification:"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, alarm

**Background**

I am in the early stages of learning iOS Development (and Objective C). After the latest tutorial I followed, I decided to take the lesson a little further.

After the tutorial, I had an Alarm Clock application that fired a `LocalNotification` at a time set by the user. Since the local notification only played the alarm sound while the app was in background mode, I didn't think it was much of an alarm clock. So I set out to add alarm functionality while the app was open and in focus.

**Where I am now**

My alarm clock application functions exactly as it should. If the app is open, the user receives a `UIAlertView` and the alarm sound.

**The Problem**

To trigger the `UIAlertView`, I am using the `didReceiveLocalNotification:` method.

There is a fairly big delay between the time set by the user and when `didReceiveLocalNotification:` is called. 38 seconds to be exact.

I may just be nitpicking, but it's killing me that I can't figure out *why*. I went out searching through GitHub to find some other examples, and they all seem to be following the same pattern as I am.

What might cause a delay like this? If this is normal behavior, what can be done to get rid of the delay?

Please let me know if any of my code might be helpful. As `didReceiveLocalNotification:` is a predefined method, and I have no control over when it is called, I'm not sure what code you might need.

**Additional Information**

*Method for setting alarm time*

```
- (void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate: (NSDate *) fireDate
{
    UILocalNotification *backgroundNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    backgroundNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
    backgroundNotification.alertBody = @"Wake Up!";
    backgroundNotification.soundName = @"My_Alarm.mp3";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: backgroundNotification];
}
```

Comment: remove launch image may be helpful in your case but i think it is not better then default functionality like your sound play at fireDate.. you can not do/apply large changes on speed up.. because each time your application launch method is call and so it take a more time to manage it ... thanks :)

Comment: Is it 38 seconds every time? As far as I remember, the local notifications uses the seconds in the moment they are set. For example if I set a notification at 09:28:33 to notify me at 10:00, the alert will come at 10:00:33. I have no idea why, but this is something I have experienced.